# Why won't this quiz work properly?

Tags: javascript

I'm very new to coding and I'm very frustrated right now, I don't see what I am missing in order to get this to work. Please help! Right now when I click the button to submit it just takes me back to the top of the page and resets the answers. It won't show me the results.

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Destiny enemy race quiz</title>
</head>
<style>
body {
    background-color: #e6ffff;
}

h1 {
    font-family: "Arial Black", Gadget, sans-serif;
    color: #000033;
    text-align: center;
}

p {
    font-family: "Trebuchet MS", Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size: 20px;
    color: #000033;
    text-align: left;
}

</style>
<body>
<h1>Which Destiny enemy race are you?</h1>
<form>
<p>If you were dresing up for Halloween, what would you dress up as?</p>
<input type="radio" name="q1" value="fallen" checked="checked"> Captain Jack Sparrow
<br><input type="radio" name="q1" value="hive"> A zombie from The Walking Dead
<br><input type="radio" name="q1" value="vex"> The Terminator
<br><input type="radio" name="q1" value="cabal"> A military soldier
<br><br>
```

This goes on for 10 total questions.

```
<input type="submit" value="Get results!" onclick="checkQuiz()">&nbsp;<input type="reset" value="Reset">
</form>
<p id="raceParagraph"></p>
</body>
<script>
function checkQuiz() {
var question = 1;
var fallen = 0;
var hive = 0;
var vex = 0;
var cabal = 0;
var answer = 1;
var youranswer = 0;
var result = '';
var choice;

for (question = 1; question <= 10; question++) {
    var selectedq = document.forms['quiz'].elements['q'+question];
        for (var i = 0; i < selectedq.length; i++) {
           if (selectedq[i].checked) {
              choice = selectedq[i].value;
           }
        }
    if (choice == 'fallen') {
        fallen++;
    }
    if (choice == 'hive') {
        hive++;
    }
    if (choice == 'vex') {
        vex++;
    }
    if (choice == 'cabal') {
        cabal++;
    }
}
if (fallen >= hive && fallen >= vex && fallen >= cabal && fallen > 0) {
     //fallen is the highest
     result = 'fallen';
  }
  else if (hive > fallen && hive >= vex && hive >= cabal && hive > 0) {
    //hive is the highest
     result = 'hive';
  }
  else if (vex > fallen && vex > hive && vex >= cabal && vex > 0) {
     //vex is the highest
     result = 'vex';
  }
   else if (cabal > fallen && cabal > hive && cabal > vex && cabal > 0) {
     //cabal is the highest
     result = 'cabal';
  }
  else {
     result = 'oops';
  }
  displayRace(result);
}

function displayRace(race) {

var image = document.createElement('img');

image.className = 'q1';

var source = document.getElementById('raceParagraph');

var text = 'Congratulations! You\'re a ' + race + '!';

switch(race) {
    case 'fallen':
        image.src =     'http://vignette4.wikia.nocookie.net/destinypedia/images/a/a9/Captain.png/revision/latest?cb=20130510122813';
        break;
    case 'hive':
        image.src = 'http://vignette2.wikia.nocookie.net/destinypedia/images/8/8c/Hive_Thrall.png/revision/latest?cb=20140609013118';
        break;
    case 'vex':
        image.src = 'http://vignette3.wikia.nocookie.net/destinypedia/images/b/bc/Vex.png/revision/latest?cb=20140609005540';
        break;
    case 'cabal':
        image.src = 'http://vignette2.wikia.nocookie.net/destinypedia/images/4/48/Cabal_Render.png/revision/latest?cb=20140609170438';
        break;
    default:
        image.src = '';
}

source.appendChild(image);

source.innerHTML += '<br>' + text;

window.onload = init;

}

</script>
</html>
```

Comment: You understand that `choice` is reassigned on every iteration where the checkbox is checked, so `choice` only captures the last value?

Comment: No I don't know that, so is that what the problem is?

Comment: Looks like more of a logical bug than a problem with displaying.

Comment: Which logic is wrong?

Comment: Are you running two accounts, "George" and "GeorgeIVV"? Because this looks the same question as [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39843367/how-do-i-make-the-results-appear-in-this-quiz#comment66976486_39843367) a couple of hours ago. Anyway, change your button from `type="submit"` to `type="button"`.

Comment: When I do that nothing at all happens when the button is clicked

Comment: Check your browser's console for JS errors, because, e.g., you are trying to reference a form by name without having given the form a name in the html.

Comment: I have checked the console for errors and I've put in console.log's but nothing shows up so I don't know what's the issue

Answer (score 1):

> *Right now when I click the button to submit it just takes me back to the top of the page and resets the answers.*

This is because you have a `type="submit"` button and you are not cancelling the default form submit behaviour - which in your case, with a form with no `action`, is basically to reload the page. Change your button to `type="button"`.

Other than that, the main problem is that your JS is trying to access a form named "quiz" but in your html you don't give the form a name. This results in an exception that will appear in your browser's console.

With those things fixed your code will work as you can see if you expand and run this snippet:

```js
function checkQuiz() {
var question = 1;
var fallen = 0;
var hive = 0;
var vex = 0;
var cabal = 0;
var answer = 1;
var youranswer = 0;
var result = '';
var choice;

for (question = 1; question <= 2; question++) {
    var selectedq = document.forms['quiz'].elements['q'+question];
        for (var i = 0; i < selectedq.length; i++) {
           if (selectedq[i].checked) {
              choice = selectedq[i].value;
           }
        }
    if (choice == 'fallen') {
        fallen++;
    }
    if (choice == 'hive') {
        hive++;
    }
    if (choice == 'vex') {
        vex++;
    }
    if (choice == 'cabal') {
        cabal++;
    }
}
if (fallen >= hive && fallen >= vex && fallen >= cabal && fallen > 0) {
     //fallen is the highest
     result = 'fallen';
  }
  else if (hive > fallen && hive >= vex && hive >= cabal && hive > 0) {
    //hive is the highest
     result = 'hive';
  }
  else if (vex > fallen && vex > hive && vex >= cabal && vex > 0) {
     //vex is the highest
     result = 'vex';
  }
   else if (cabal > fallen && cabal > hive && cabal > vex && cabal > 0) {
     //cabal is the highest
     result = 'cabal';
  }
  else {
     result = 'oops';
  }
  displayRace(result);
}

function displayRace(race) {

var image = document.createElement('img');

image.className = 'q1';

var source = document.getElementById('raceParagraph');

var text = 'Congratulations! You\'re a ' + race + '!';

switch(race) {
    case 'fallen':
        image.src =     'http://vignette4.wikia.nocookie.net/destinypedia/images/a/a9/Captain.png/revision/latest?cb=20130510122813';
        break;
    case 'hive':
        image.src = 'http://vignette2.wikia.nocookie.net/destinypedia/images/8/8c/Hive_Thrall.png/revision/latest?cb=20140609013118';
        break;
    case 'vex':
        image.src = 'http://vignette3.wikia.nocookie.net/destinypedia/images/b/bc/Vex.png/revision/latest?cb=20140609005540';
        break;
    case 'cabal':
        image.src = 'http://vignette2.wikia.nocookie.net/destinypedia/images/4/48/Cabal_Render.png/revision/latest?cb=20140609170438';
        break;
    default:
        image.src = '';
}

source.appendChild(image);

source.innerHTML += '<br>' + text;
}
```

```html
<h1>Which Destiny enemy race are you?</h1>
<form name="quiz">
<p>If you were dresing up for Halloween, what would you dress up as?</p>
<input type="radio" name="q1" value="fallen" checked="checked"> Captain Jack Sparrow
<br><input type="radio" name="q1" value="hive"> A zombie from The Walking Dead
<br><input type="radio" name="q1" value="vex"> The Terminator
<br><input type="radio" name="q1" value="cabal"> A military soldier
<br><br>
<p>Some other question?</p>
<input type="radio" name="q2" value="fallen" checked="checked"> Answer 1
<br><input type="radio" name="q2" value="hive"> Answer 2
<br><input type="radio" name="q2" value="vex"> Answer 3
<br><input type="radio" name="q2" value="cabal"> Answer 4
<br><br>
  <input type="button" value="Get results!" onclick="checkQuiz()">&nbsp;<input type="reset" value="Reset">
</form>
<p id="raceParagraph"></p>
```

You should also remove the `window.onload = init;` from the end of your second function. Even aside from the fact that you don't have a function called `init`, it doesn't make sense to set a `window.onload` handler after the page has loaded.

Comment: Thanks for explaining it to me. The last little thing I'm trying to fix now is to have the image size be constrained and centered, along with the text. I've tried putting                                                                          `.race {
 max-width: 200px;
 width: 100%;
}` in the style section but it doesn't effect it for some reason.

Comment: You don't have a class `race`, your output has id `raceParagraph`, so try `#raceParagraph { max-width: 200px; width: 100%; }
#raceParagraph img { max-width: 100%; }`

Comment: Ah, I got it. It was .q1